# Building OpenCV 3.1 Error Message in Ubuntu 16

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.1

I am trying to build from source opencv so that I can have access to the sift/surf libraries. I am running into the problem where it is getting 82% of the way before stopping. I have tried disabling packages I thought might be the problem with little luck. This is how I built the files:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules     -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

and this is the error I received:

Screenshot of Error

[image]

I am new to programming and have spent about a 2weeks trying to troubleshoot this myself. So any help would be appreciated on what is going wrong, Thanks!

Comment: first result in google: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6677

Comment: So I need to remove the cuda installation in order to download Opencv?

Comment: I would recommend to just checkout the version with the patch as described in [this comment](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6677#issuecomment-262596837) , I would not recommend to remove cuda, you can also just disable the corresponding CMAKE option to disable building with cuda if that's what you want.

Comment: I guess if you already downloaded the sources you could also just manually change [this one line](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6510/files)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will give it a try!